# How to change the newly created default view on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time I use `scaffold` to generate related files.

I have to modify the `*.html.erb` to `*.html.haml` and change the content to my preference layout.

Is there any better practice to achieve this ?

Thanks.

For example, I have the these columns in my model `:excel, :model, :result_file, :user_id, :version, :xml`.

I omit the default `index.html.erb` file (the `scaffold` generated it for me).

and I will change the `index.html.erb` in my custom default layout.

I'd rather every time the scaffold will generate this pattern for me.

I know I can modified the template file under my `.rvm`

`~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold`

But is it a good practice ?

```
%h1 ND 
%div{:class => "hero-unit"}
  %large
    使用前請先安裝 Firefox plugin 
%h2.center
  = link_to "新增一筆測試", new_nd_multi_lang_path, |
   :class=> "btn btn-primary autotest"
%table#rf_tbl.table.table-condensed.table-striped
  %tr
    %th Date
    %th User
    %th Model
    %th Version
    %th Excel
    %th Xml
    %th Result file
    %th
    %th
    %th
  - @nd_multi_langs.each do |nd_multi_lang|
    %tr.center
      %td= nd_multi_lang.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")  
      %td= nd_multi_lang.user.email
      %td= nd_multi_lang.model
      %td= nd_multi_lang.version
      %td
        = link_to 'Excel', nd_multi_lang.excel.to_s
      %td
        = link_to 'XML', nd_multi_lang.xml.to_s
      %td
        = link_to 'Download', nd_multi_lang.result_file.to_s, :class=> "btn btn-info"

%br/
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the gem for haml-rails, should do that by default.

You editted your question to ask something entirely different >.<

Here is a guide to answer to your new question.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates